# Autonomous microservices

Tags: microservices

Going through literature on microservices, a common concept is that if a microservice relies on another service to service a direct request, it is not truly autonomous.

Does it mean truly autonomous microservices don't interact at all? How are systems supposed to work then?

Comment: Please check out this link: https://dev.to/designpuddle/apps--microservices--what-you-need-to-know-autonomy-and-the-challenges-you-will-face-39e1

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when you decide go with Microservices architecture you need to be decoupling your business logic between your "services" as much as possible. Otherwise, you need to combine them in 1 service.